# A method for an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

What is the most concise and explicit way to write a method for this?

> Given an array `a` of numbers and a number `n`, find the `n` consecutive elements of `a` whose sum is the largest.
>
> Return the largest sum and the index of the first element in the group.

For example, with `a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]` and `n = 2`, the
result would be a sum `3` and position `6`.

Answer (score 6):

```
arr = [1,3,2,4,3,5,2,1,3,4,2,5,1]
size = 3
```

*Inefficient but pretty*

```
arr.each_cons(size).with_index.map { |a,i| [a.inject(:+), i] }.max_by(&:first)
  #=> [12, 3]
```

*Efficient but whupped with an ugly stick*<sup>1</sup>

```
tot = arr[0,size].inject(:+)
(1..arr.size-size).each_with_object([tot, 0]) do |i, best|
  tot += arr[i+size-1] - arr[i-1]
  best.replace([tot, i]) if tot > best.first
end
  #=> [12, 3]
```

*Steps performed by the pretty one*

```
enum0 = arr.each_cons(size)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1]:each_cons(3)> 
enum1 = enum0.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1]:
  #       each_cons(3)>:with_index>
```

Carefully examine the above return value for `enum1`. You will see it is effectively a "compound" enumerator. We can see the values that `enum1` will generate and pass to `map` by converting it to an array:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[[1, 3, 2], 0], [[3, 2, 4], 1], [[2, 4, 3], 2], [[4, 3, 5], 3],
  #    [[3, 5, 2], 4], [[5, 2, 1], 5], [[2, 1, 3], 6], [[1, 3, 4], 7],
  #    [[3, 4, 2], 8], [[4, 2, 5], 9], [[2, 5, 1], 10]]
```

Continuing:

```
b = enum1.map { |a,i| [a.inject(:+), i] }
  #=> [[6, 0], [9, 1], [9, 2], [12, 3], [10, 4], [8, 5],
  #    [6, 6], [8, 7], [9, 8], [11, 9], [8, 10]]
```

Note the since the first element of `enum1` that `map` passes to the block is `[[1, 3, 2], 0]`, the two block variables are assigned as follows (using *parallel* or *multiple* assignment):

```
a, i = [[1, 3, 2], 0]
  #=> [[1, 3, 2], 0] 
a #=> [1, 3, 2] 
i #=> 0
```

and the block calculation is performed:

```
[a.inject(:+), i]
  #=> [6, 0]
```

Lastly,

```
b.max_by(&:first)
  #=> [12, 3]
```

[Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) determines the largest value among

```
b.map(&:first)
  #=> [6, 9, 9, 12, 10, 8, 6, 8, 9, 11, 8]
```

*Steps performed by the less pretty one*

```
a = arr[0,size]
  #=> [1, 3, 2] 
tot = a.inject(:+)
  #=> 6 
enum = (1..arr.size-size).each_with_object([tot, 0])
  #=> (1..13-3).each_with_object([6, 0])
  #=> #<Enumerator: 1..10:each_with_object([6, 0])> 
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, [6, 0]], [2, [6, 0]], [3, [6, 0]], [4, [6, 0]], [5, [6, 0]],
  #    [6, [6, 0]], [7, [6, 0]], [8, [6, 0]], [9, [6, 0]], [10, [6, 0]]] 
enum.each do |i, best|
  tot += arr[i+size-1] - arr[i-1]
  best.replace([tot, i]) if tot > best.first
end
  #=> [12, 3]
```

The first element of `enum`, `[1, [6, 0]]`, is passed to the block, assigned to the block variables and the block calculation is performed:

```
i, best = [1, [6, 0]]
  #=> [1, [6, 0]] 
i #=> 1 
best
  #=> [6, 0] 
tot += arr[i+size-1] - arr[i-1]
  # tot = 6 + arr[1+3-1] - arr[1-1]
  #     = 6 + 4 - 1
  #     = 9 
best.replace([tot, i]) if tot > best.first
  #=> best.replace([9, 1]) if 9 > 6
  #=> [9, 1] 
best
  #=> [9, 1]
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

<sup>1 Credit to [Bo Diddley](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=A5jHLJce1Go) (at 2:51)</sup>

Comment: That is pretty cool code.  I wish I can upvote, but my credentials is not valid yet.